# Why my Android ViewModel cannot persistent data?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel

I`m programing with Jetpack Compose.
I request data from net and save it into a ViewModel in a Composable,
but when I want to use the data in other Composable, the ViewModel returns null

```kotlin
// ViewModel:
class PartViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val mPicRepository: PicRepository = PicRepository()

    private val _partsResult: MutableLiveData<PicResp> = MutableLiveData()
    val partsResilt: LiveData<PicResp> get() = _partsResult
    fun getPartsFromImage(id: Long) {
        mPicRepository.getCloudPic(id, _partsResult)
    }
}
```

```kotlin
// Composable which request data
@Composable
fun PagePhotoDetail(imageId: Long, navController: NavHostController) {
    val vm: PartViewModel = viewModel()
    vm.getPartsFromImage(imageId)

    partsState.value?.data?.let {
        Logger.d(it.parts)        // this log show correct data
    }
}
```

```kotlin
// Composable which use data
@Composable
fun PagePartListFromImage(navController: NavHostController) {
    val vm: PartViewModel = viewModel()
    Logger.d(vm.partsResilt.value)        // this log cannot get data and show null
}
```

Comment: Because it's not the same ViewModel instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating two different instances of your viewmodel. You need to initialise the viewmodel like `val vm by viewmodels<PartViewModel>`

Then pass this viewmodel as a parameter inside the Composable. You're done!

Well, if you still wish to initialise it inside a Composable, you can use `val vm by viewmodel<PartViewModel>`.

`viewModel<>` instead of `viewModels<>`

Comment: it works outside of @Composable, but how can I get the same effect in @composable?

Comment: Please check the edited answer, and forget about the previous comments